# Javascript code not executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

In my webform, I want to have several text fields which have values 'please enter a date', 'enter your age', etc. which disappear when the text field gains focus and the user begins to enter data.  I am trying to program this functionality with Javascript/JQuery however for some reason my javascript code is not executing.

In the head of my html document I have included the source for what I am writing as well as JQuery:

```
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <script src="{% static 'jquery-1.11.0.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'text_area.js' %}"></script>
</head>
```

further down in the document I have the code for a form which contains one of my text fields:

```
<form action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
     <td> <input id="expire_date"
           name="expire_date"
           type="text"
           value="{{list_expire_date}}"/>
     </td>
...
</form>
```

Here is the source for *text_area.js:*

```
$('#expire_date').focusin(function(){
    if(this.value == '{{list_expire_date}}')
    {
        this.value = '';
        showCalendarControl(this);
    }
}).focusout(function(){
    if( this.value == '')
    {
        this.value = '{{list_expire_date}}';
        hideCalendarControl(this);
    }
})
```

Comment: This is what HTML5 placeholders are for! Did you wrap the code in document ready ?

Answer (score 0):

The "focusin" event fires when an input **within** the element gains focus:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

You want to change your code to:

```
$('#expire_date').on('focus', function(){
if(this.value == '{{list_expire_date}}')
{
    this.value = '';
    showCalendarControl(this);
}
}).on('blur', function(){
if( this.value == '')
{
    this.value = '{{list_expire_date}}';
    hideCalendarControl(this);
}
})
```

Or, if you're going to have multiple inputs, bind the "focusin" event handler to the form.

Comment: How would I bind the event handler to the form?

Comment: The same was as you are doing to bind to the input: `$('form').focusin()`. However, I'd suggest something like this: `$('form').on('focus', 'input.classname', function() {}).on('blur', 'input.classname', function() {});`.